# Is it possible to press F1-F12 buttons with javascript and html link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript to type input values like name, address etc in html form in Devnagari (Hindi -India) language and in English with toggle. For that **F9 button on keyboard** to be pressed to toggle between Hindi And English language.

Is it possible to provide a link / button to user which will work as F9 when pressed and toggle languages... ?

currently I am using following javascript to enable hindi and english language to type in input fields in html form with F9 as toggle language key..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    devnagari.addLanguage(DevIndic,"Hindi"); 
    devnagari.enable();
    devnagari.setToggleKey(120, true, false); 
</script>
```

With this script I can toggle hindi and english with pressing F9 button on keyboard. **I want to keep a link/button to toggle this...** when user clicks on it, language get toggled instead of pressing F9 button

Comment: sure you can add click event on button and switch between hindi and english

Comment: ok... can i have a sample code for this click event as I am very weak in javascript..

Comment: You can detect which key got pressed by using [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) Please go through the whole documentation for examples and reference to know which key has what code.

Comment: @KarelG I do not want to detect which key is pressed... It is 120 (F9)... I want to create a button to show above form to toggle between languages instead of manually pressing F9 button

Comment: oh, just create a button. hook a click event on that button. Then when the button is clicked, just call the function that swaps the language.